# Conversion of JSON from unicode to original format

Tags: c#, unicode, persian

I have a JSON string result(in persian language) from a webservive.

But the results from the web service are as this:

> "\u0622\u062f\u0631\u0633 \u0627\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u0644"

While the original text is as follows:

> عملیات انجام شد

how to Conversion from unicode to original format C#

this is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webserver.com/");

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string strContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response text is UTF-8 encoded? I believe `response.ContentEncoding` is a thing if you're not sure

Comment: try it but no resolve my problem

Comment: How are you observing the result? Bear in mind that the debugger will often display strings as "what you would type into C# source code to generate this string" rather than what the string "really" is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like JSON. You would need [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c).

To confirm it, you could take the output and run it through an online decoder for example http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
{ "a": "\u0622\u062f\u0631\u0633 \u0627\u06cc\u0645\u06cc\u0644" }
```

Result is
[image]

So to parse that in C#

```
string strContent = readStream.ReadToEnd(); 

dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strContent);
```

You should be able to find out what structure is being returned by the web service - usually this is documented. Not much point creating a web service unless you tell people how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c